# What does "this" refer to for each constructors?

Tags: c#

Please, explain what " : this()" refer to.Cant I use "base" instead of it.
When I move cursor on "this" it displays another Constructor .
Or when I replace it with "base" it gives this error: "object doesnt contain a constructor that takes 1 argument".

> ```
> class Employee
>     {
>         private string name;
>         private string surname;
>         private DateTime birthday;
>         private double height;
>         private double salary;
>         public string Name { get { return name; } set { if (name != value) { name = value; } } }
>         public string Surname { get { return surname; } set { if (surname != value) { surname = value; } } }
>         public DateTime Birthday { get { return birthday; } set { if (birthday != value) { birthday = value; } } }
>         public double Height { get { return height; } set { if (height != value) { height = value; } } }
>         public double Salary { get { return salary; } set { if (salary != value) { salary = value; } } }
>         public string Full { get { return name + " " + surname; } }
>         public Employee() {
>             name = "Mina";
>             surname = "Babayeva";
>             birthday = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-19);
>             height=175;
>             salary = 3500;
>         }   
>
>         public Employee(string name, string surname, DateTime birthday, double height, double salary) : this( name,  surname)
>         {
>             this.birthday = birthday;
>             this.height = height;
>             this.salary = salary;
>         }
>         public Employee(string name) : this()
>         {
>             this.name = name;
>         }
>         public Employee(string name, string surname) : this(name)
>         {
>             this.surname = surname;
>         }
>
>
>         public void Print()
>         {
>             Console.WriteLine("Name is {0}\nSurname is {1}\nHeight is {2}\nBirthday is {3}\nSalary is {4}", 
>                 this.Name, this.Surname, this.Height, this.Birthday.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), this.Salary);
>         }
>
>
> ////////////////////////////////
>  Employee a = new Employee();
>             Employee b = new Employee("Adil", "Babayev");
>              Employee c = new Employee("Zumrud","Babayeva",DateTime.Now.AddYears(-52),167,1000000);
>             Employee e = new Employee("Hanna");
>
>
>             a.Print();
>             Console.WriteLine();
>             b.Print();
>             Console.WriteLine();
>             c.Print();
>             Console.WriteLine();
>             e.Print();
>             Console.WriteLine();
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime you create a constructor for a class, you are actually creating an instance as a single copy of an object.
The this keyword is that instance.

Example Class Apple : Orange {}

public Apple ()
:this() {}
This. is a reference to the instance of Apple.

When calling base on a class constructor, you are calling the derived class constructor.
Public Apple() 
: base() {}

would return the Orange Class Constructor, not Apples!
Huge difference between the two!!

Please look into C# Constructor Chaining. 
MSDN has great examples and documentations in regards to your quest.
Good luck my friend

Kind Regards.

Comment: You may want to double check your syntax and formatting on this one.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, `this` refers to the constructor for the current class. `base` refers to the constructor for the base/inherited class. So no, they are not interchangeable.

More info: [MSDN Using Constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx)